# Com port InputStream

Tags: java, io

I am sending a text message to mobile number. I write the data using a o/p stream and read the data using i/p stream from Port. The o/p stream is working properly, but I can not read the data from the i/p stream. Here is my code:

```
public class SendMsg implements  SerialPortEventListener
{
    Enumeration portList;
    CommPortIdentifier portId;
    SerialPort serialPort;

    OutputStream outputStream;
    InputStream inputStream;
    Thread readThread;

     String messageString;
     String messageString1;

     String strResponse="";
     SendMsg pWriter;
     String msg[]=new String[200];
     int ix=0;

     boolean msgEnd=true;

    String className;
     static Enumeration ports;
    static CommPortIdentifier pID;
    static String messageToSend = "ComPortSendMsg deatails!\n";


    public SendMsg(String className) throws NoSuchPortException, IOException
    {

            this.className=className;

           ports = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
         System.out.println("ports name"+ports);
        while(ports.hasMoreElements())
        {
            pID = (CommPortIdentifier)ports.nextElement();
            System.out.println("Port Name " + pID.getName());

            if (pID.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL)
            {
                System.out.println("Port Name 1 " + pID.getName());
                if (pID.getName().equals("COM1"))
                {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Port Name 2 " + pID.getName());
                         System.out.println("COM1 found");
                         serialPort=(SerialPort)pID.open(className, 9600);

                         outputStream=serialPort.getOutputStream();
                         inputStream=serialPort.getInputStream();
                         break;
                    } catch (PortInUseException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(SendMsg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }


                }
            }
        }
}

      public void closePort()
    {
        try
        {
            inputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Finished2");
            outputStream.close();
            System.out.println("Finished1");

            serialPort.close();
            System.out.println("Finished");


        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Close Error"+e);
        }


    }


    public void send(String phno,String msg)
    {
String s = "AT+CMGF="+1;
System.out.println("AT+CMGF command :"+s);

       messageString = "AT+CMGS=\""+phno+"\"\r";
        messageString1 = msg+"\n" +(char)26;
        System.out.println("AT CMGS "+messageString);
        System.out.println("AT CMGS  "+messageString1);


        try
        {
            outputStream.write(s.getBytes());

           System.out.print("this is send try block");
         outputStream.write(messageString.getBytes());

             outputStream.write(messageString1.getBytes());

               Thread.sleep(2000);

     byte[] b = new byte[1000];
     String r="";
     String r1="";

     System.out.println(inputStream.available());
     while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    int n = inputStream.read(b);
                    System.out.println("number of bytes"+n);
                    r= new String(b);

     }
     System.out.println("this is input stream msg"+r);
        }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
           System.out.println(e);
          }

    }
public static void main(String args[]) throws NoSuchPortException, IOException
        {

            SendMsg f=new SendMsg("Msg Sending");
            f.send("9884345649","Wish U Happy");
 System.out.println("---------END--------");





            f.closePort();


        }

    @Override
    public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent spe) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }



}
```

Comment: What happens when you read from the input port?

Comment: it is showing output is 0. This is the code for that  System.out.println(inputStream.available());
     while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    int n = inputStream.read(b);
                    System.out.println("number of bytes"+n);
                    r= new String(b);
                    
     }

Comment: Does it help if you flush the output stream after you write to it?  Also, if the writing can block your program will freeze because you are running everything in one thread.

Comment: i am using flush means it is throwing an flowing exception         


java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: eis
AT CMGS AT+CMGS="9884345649"
 at gnu.io.RXTXPort.nativeDrain(Native Method)
AT CMGS  Wish U Happy

0
this is input stream msg
---------END--------
Finished2
Finished1
 at gnu.io.RXTXPort$SerialOutputStream.flush(RXTXPort.java:1201)
 at javaapplication4.SendMsg.send(SendMsg.java:118)
 at javaapplication4.SendMsg.main(SendMsg.java:155)

Answer (score 0):

You should be reading the InputStream from within the `serialEvent(..)` method.

Something like this:

```
public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent spe) {
        int data;
        String r;
        try
        {
            int len = 0;
            while ( ( data = in.read()) > -1 )
            {
                buffer[len++] = (byte) data;
            }
            r = new String(buffer,0,len);
            System.out.println("this is input stream msg"+r);
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
}
```

Secondly, you can put in a long sleep, e.g. `Thread.sleep(100000);`, in the main method, before 
calling `f.closePort();`.

Or, potentially the `serialEvent(..)` method could close the port after receiving the inputStream's data.

Hope this helps!

Comment: note: your reading into a byte array is more efficient & appropriate, but the main thing is to wait for the serialEvent to fire.